# Use null result of exec sp_execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have some dynamic SQL that I use to see if a certain property for a certain client is in a table. If so, it will return the value, if not, it will return null. However, I would like it to return a default value if the property is not found.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[customers](
    [customer] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [key_name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [key_value] [nvarchar](256) NULL
) 
GO


INSERT INTO [test].[customers]
           ([customer]
           ,[key_name]
           ,[key_value])
     VALUES
           ('JohnDoe'
           ,'periodlength'
           ,'3')
GO
```

The Dynamic SQL:

```
declare @customer as nvarchar(256) = 'JohnDoe'
declare @table as nvarchar(256) = 'test.customers'

declare @sql as nvarchar(4000)
set @sql = 'select [key_value] from ' +  @table + ' where [key_name]= ''periodlength'' and customer= ''' + @customer + ''''
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

So when Qqerying for John Doe you get result 3 which is perfect. However, I would like to reurn 1 for Jane Doe. So I was thinking along the lines 
`IF exec sp_executesql @sql IS NULL 1 ELSE exec sp_executesql @sql`
but that doesn't work.

How to change my dynamic query so that is returns a default value if the property is not found?

Comment: Your dynamic SQL is not safe, as it's vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Read [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/) over on my blog to learn how to make it safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following query but this usage only return a single value;

```
declare @customer as nvarchar(256) = 'JohnDoe'
    declare @table as nvarchar(256) = 'test.customers'
    DECLARE @ValReturn nvarchar(50)

    declare @sql as nvarchar(4000)
    set @sql = 'select @ValOutPut=[key_value] from ' +  @table + ' where [key_name]= ''periodlength'' and customer= ''' + @customer + ''''
    exec sp_executesql @sql , N'@ValOutPut nvarchar(25) OUTPUT' ,@ValOutPut = @ValReturn OUTPUT 

    BEGIN 
    IF @ValReturn IS NULL
    SELECT NULL
    ELSE
    SELECT @ValReturn
    END
```

Comment: This is still a security risk. `@table` should be white-listed and `@customer` should be parameterized. You should also read the blog post I've recommended to the OP.

Comment: I read your blog, useful read. Security is not a large concern here, this is a POC. However, I have far bigger problems if someone without permissions ever gets to this database ;)